# JPA Join table with SELECT

Tags: java, sql, jpa, join

I have a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT h.name, h.created_date,  tbl.*
FROM my_table tbl
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT name, max(created_date) created_date FROM my_table GROUP BY name) h
  ON tbl.name = h.name;
```

It returns the row from my_table (which has multiple for name="") along with the maximum created_date for that name.

Is there a way to replicate this in a JPQL query?

Here is the gist of the Entity class, it's quite simple:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
@XmlRootElement
public class MyTable implements Serializable {


  private BigDecimal tableId;
  private String name;
  private Date createdDate;

  // ...

  @Id
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "TABLE_ID")
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "TBL_ID_SEQ")
  public BigDecimal getTableId() {
    return tableId;
  }

  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "NAME")
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "CREATED_DATE", insertable = false)
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  public Date getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
  }

  // ... getters/setters

}
```

Comment: and your classes are? because you do know that JPQL is oriented around classes/fields not tables/columns

Comment: I did know that. I'm quite new to jpa to be honest and I'm not that familiar with jpql yet. The entity class will be myTable and the name field that I'm trying to join on is a string. Perhaps this is not something that can be done directly?

Comment: Maybe i need another entity class that just returns the max date and the name field? Rather than try with the same entity

Answer (score 0):

Just reading your question I guess you do not need another entity. Entities in JPA are the same like tables in SQL. Usually there is a 1:1 relationship between entities and tables. You just have to know how to invoke a query using JPQ. You need a entity manager, which invokes your statement.

`EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PersistenceUnit");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();`

You have to define your persistence unit, i.e. in a pom file, or a config java file. So done you can go on coding something like this:

`Query q = em.createQuery( "Your query in sql syntax as a string object" );`

In respect to your entities and invoked query you will receive a List using

`List<object> resultOfMyQuery = q.getResultList();`

This is only one short example. But hopefully you got some buzzwords to look for ;)